# How to get squeue only to return unique job_ids

Tags: slurm

So I have some code that I want to grab all job_ids from a list of jobnames

`squeue --nohead --format %F --name {JOB_NAME}`

However, when the job in question is an array job, it returns multiple copies of the same job id. Is there a way I can get squeue to only return a single copy of a job_id from an array job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier way to do is to use the command `uniq`.

```
squeue --nohead --format %F --name {JOB_NAME} | uniq
```

Pipe the output of `squeue` to the `uniq` command.